# Bootstrap ajax call from popover contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have to call ajax or any kind of post request from contents in `#id`.
And `#id` is hidden like this:

```
<div id="mycontents" style="display: none;">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="click_id">Click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I trigger ajax call from this `#mycontents`?

```
$('#id').popover({
    trigger : 'hover',
    delay : {
        show : 1,
        hide : 10000
    },
    html : true,
    content : function() {
        return $('#mycontents').html();
    }
})
```

The problem is some browsers ignore `display: none` elements so I cannot trigger any events from it.

For example, when I click the button, I want to trigger this:

```
$('#click_id').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/click_id",
        async: true,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: please write your   clear requirement so as to stackoverflow can give you a proper solution

Comment: Added more description. Thanks. `display: none` just disables everything...

Comment: What do you mean *"How do I trigger ajax call from this #mycontents?"* When do you want to trigger this request..? and what are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: Just added javascript code that I want to trigger. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `$('#click_id:visible').click(` or `$('#click_id:hidden').click(`. - based on your requirements.

Comment: `:visible` or `:hidden`  doesn't help

Comment: @cvxv31431asdas  - did you get any further with this? Would be keen to see a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#id').popover({
    trigger : 'hover',
    delay : {
        show : 1,
        hide : 10000
    },
    html : true,
    content : function() {
        var myhtml = $('#mycontents').html();
        $('#mycontents', myhtml).removeAttr('style');
        return myhtml
    }
})
```